# Set image in CALayer like UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I am Developing a application that when I paint on a layer of CALayer type, the path I draw with my finger, becomes transparent overall. For now I can do it with a flat color but I need rather than a flat color, has an image:

[image]
[image]

The code that I use for these is this:

RevealLayer.swift

```
import UIKit

class RevealLayer: CALayer {
        var drawingPath = UIBezierPath()
    func drawingPathMethod()->(UIBezierPath){

        drawingPath.moveToPoint(CGPointZero)
        drawingPath.lineWidth = 200.0
        drawingPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound

        return drawingPath

    }

     override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)

        UIColor.grayColor().set()
        CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound)
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds)
        self.opacity = 0.8
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 10.0)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear)
        drawingPath.stroke()
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {
           var path = RevealLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = false

        var img = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)

        img.image = UIImage(named: "colour_roca_02.png")
        self.view.addSubview(img)

        path.drawingPath.lineWidth = 50.0

        path.frame = self.view.bounds

        path.setNeedsDisplay()

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(path)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        var location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        path.drawingPath.moveToPoint(location)
        path.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        var location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        path.drawingPath.addLineToPoint(location)
        path.setNeedsDisplay()

    }

}
```

EDIT:

I put this code:

```
 var imageForColor = UIImage(named: "colour_roca_01.png")       
    var imageColor = UIColor(patternImage: imageForColor!)
    imageColor.set()
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I try to draw in Rect and this is what happend:

```
var rect: CGRect = self.frame
        imageForColor?.drawInRect(rect)
```

[image]

EDIT: This is solved using different images with different sizes, one for each posible screen size.

Comment: look at `+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image`

Comment: Ok, I edit to show the new problem